# Как в Telegram узнать username пользователя имея id?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Возможно ли узнать username пользователя имея id? Если да, то как?

Comment: Ответы на простые вопросы по телеботу можно найти на [репозитории pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)

Comment: можно получить с помощью
bot.get_chat(message.from_user.id).username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через `message.from_user.username` насколько я знаю можно узнать username только если этот пользователь отправит сообщение боту.
Решил эту задачу таким способом: `bot.get_chat_member(userid, userid)`.
Полный код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["getuser"])
def answer(message):
    if (message.from_user.id == 365156441):
        userid = int(message.text.split(maxsplit=1)[1])
        UsrInfo = bot.get_chat_member(userid, userid).user
        bot.send_message(365156441, "Id: " + str(UsrInfo.id) + "\nFirst Name: " + str(UsrInfo.first_name) + "\nLast Name: " + str(UsrInfo.last_name) +
                            "\nUsername: @" + str(UsrInfo.username))
```

Проверкой '`if (message.from_user.id == 365156441)`' Я проверяю отправлено ли сообщение от меня(То есть эту команду могу выполнить только я), его можно заменить на ваш ид либо на что-то другое(Там проверку в бд админ ли пользователь).

Answer (score 5):

Если речь идет именно об API как таковом, то там есть функция [users.getFullUser](https://core.telegram.org/method/users.getFullUser), которая в качестве параметра принимает `id` пользователя.
Если речь идет об обработке сообщения в хендлере в телеграм-боте с использованием `telebot`, то username содержится в

```
message.from_user.username
```