# Python Aiogram | Как получить username из userid?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Как имея id пользователя получить его username, используя Aiogram?

Comment: Никак. Разве что из собственной бд, где вы храните эти данные.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в Telegram узнать username пользователя имея id?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/906172/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-telegram-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-username-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%8f-id)